# MonoTouch: Using SetBackgroundImage() throws Selector error

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have a simple button to be added to a UINavigationBar, Min OS is 3.2 and we compile with the default compiler. I have MT 5.0:

```
            saleImg = UIImage.FromFileUncached (shoppingImg);
            saleButton = new UIBarButtonItem ("", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, (s, o) => {ItunesHelper.Open (); });
            saleButton.SetBackgroundImage(saleImg,UIControlState.Normal,UIBarMetrics.Default);
            saleButton.SetBackgroundImage(saleImg,UIControlState.Selected, UIBarMetrics.Default);
            saleButton.SetBackgroundImage(saleImg,UIControlState.Highlighted, UIBarMetrics.Default);
```

But when run it throws the error:

`Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[UIBarButtonItem setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x76d4d00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UIBarButtonItem.SetBackgroundImage` method was introduced with [iOS 5](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/setBackButtonBackgroundImage%3aforState%3abarMetrics%3a). Since you are getting an "unrecognized selector..." message, I can only assume that you are running the app on a device with an iOS version older than 5.0.

If you want your app to be backwards compatible, create a button and initialize the `UIBarButtonItem` with the `UIBarButtonItem(UIView)` constructor:

```
UIButton button = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.Custom);
button.SetBackgroundImage(saleImg, UIControlState.Normal);
button.TouchUpInside += (s, o) => {ItunesHelper.Open (); };
UIBarButtonItem saleButton = new UIBarButtonItem(button);
```

Setting the minimum OS version does not mean that MonoDevelop or the compiler will inform you of API compatibilities. It is merely a setting in Info.plist which will determine if your app will appear on the App Store for devices of that version or not.